# \p{InLatin1Supplement} is an unknown unicode-character-property-name in Regex

Tags: java, regex, unicode

The docs for `java.util.regex.Pattern` specify:

> Blocks are specified with the prefix In, as in InMongolian, or by
> using the keyword block (or its short form blk) as in block=Mongolian
> or blk=Mongolian.
>
> The block names supported by Pattern are the valid block names
> accepted and defined by UnicodeBlock.forName.

and there exists a constant `Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT` which does get found by `UnicodeBlock.forName`.

Either way, I'm getting a

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {InLatin1Supplement} near index 21
\p{InLatin1Supplement}
                     ^
```

Whats up with that?

Comment: Try `\p{InLatin_1_Supplement}`

Comment: I'd rather check in the code, not at regex101, it differs from the real Java environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode property class in Java looks like

```
\p{InLatin_1_Supplement}
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/zWaeJM):

```java
String s = "ëè";
System.out.println(s.matches("\\p{InLatin_1_Supplement}+")); // -> true
```